# Transform a nonconvex problem into a convex problem using perspective function

Tags: convex-optimization

Suppose I have the problem
$$
\text{minimize  } f_0(x)\\
\text{subject to  } tf_1(x) \leq r
$$
with variables $t,x \in \mathbb{R}$ and $f_0, f_1$ are convex.
The constraint is not convex, so I was thinking using a variable $y = t*x$ then I can write the constraint as $tf_1(y/t) \leq r$ which is now convex. But the problem then is that the objective is no longer convex, since it is $f_0(y/t)$.

Comment: What is the question? Why is the transformed constraint convex?

Comment: Try setting $y=1/t$ instead?

Comment: Am I still using perspective function then? I'm not sure what $y$ maps to.

Comment: Not all problems can be transformed into a convex problem...

Comment: But this one is supposed to be so.

Comment: Then you need to give more information. If $f_1$ convex? What properties does $f_0$ have???

Comment: Both of them are convex.